# Cannot create new ipython notebook or start jupyter

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Whenever I try to start Jupyter ipython notebook. I get the following error[image]

Sometimes, after restarting the system I am able to start the ipython notebook, I cannot create a notebook and it gives me the error saying Forbidden.

My command Prompt also says 0 active kernels

[image]
Anyone else have this issue or know the answer to this problem

Comment: It seems that you are able to start the notebook but not able to access it via a browser. Are you behind some kind of proxy? Try disabling your proxy ([hint](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Proxy-Settings)) and report back.

Comment: It looks like you have a proxy set up. In the proxy configuration, make sure that it bypasses the proxy for `localhost`. Here's where to set that in Firefox: http://imgur.com/EydSNjy

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this issue too. It seems to be a bug because I restarted my PC and It would work normally again. It's been weeks I don't have this issue anymore and I didn't do anything to intentionally solve it.